# How to concatenate all "mkv" files using ffmpeg?

Tags: join, video, ffmpeg, video-processing, mkv

How can I concatenate all of my files in a folder with `mkv` extension? I know that I can specify specific files using that command:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:00019.MTS|00020.MTS|00021.MTS|00022.MTS" output.mp4
```

but I am not sure how to change it so that it executes the same over a large number of video files. How can I do this?

Comment: Use the [concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer)

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've used `ffmpeg` a couple of times to do this.  I mostly use the concatenate to 'edit-out' bad video from a scratched DVD.  I rip the good bits and then use concatenate.  I find it quite satisfactory.

Here's the recipe iI used.

```
   ffmpeg  -loglevel info -f concat -safe 0  -i join-Title.ffmpeg -c copy   "Whole Title.mkv"
```

The file `join-Title.ffmpeg`  looks like this, for 3 snippets ripped from the original DVD.

```
 ################
 #
 ##  ffmpeg  -loglevel info -f concat -safe 0  -i join-Title.ffmpeg -c copy   "Whole Title.mkv"
 #
 file    '/home/media/title/Title A.mkv'
 file    '/home/media/title/Title B.mkv'
 file    '/home/media/title/Title C.mkv'
```

This page has a simple explaination for the steps involved.

- https://ma.ttias.be/use-ffmpeg-combine-multiple-videos/

Comment: The official docs are succinct and give some ways to generate the file list on different platforms: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate   For example, for Windows Powershell:  `foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem .\*.mkv) {echo "file '$i'" >> mylist.txt}`

Comment: Here's a one-liner I use `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in *.mkv; do echo "file '$(pwd)/$f"; done) output.mkv`

Comment: @iforwms That's a nasty one-liner as it misses `-c copy`. `ffmpeg` will start encoding stuff!